# Displaying images with titles in order from database

Tags: php, css, image, alignment

All I want is to display my images in a very simple way, same as in google search for images. I have the image with, `width:71px; height:59px` ... and under the image I want to `center` the title of the image, and displaying in this way multiple images in one row, and then in the second row and so for the next one.

How to make the `CSS` for all of this?

Here is what I have until now, to display the images from database, but at this moment, it display my image and my title everything in "one column" and not side by side.

PHP CODE:

```
<div class="thumb">

        <?php
        $sql_res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE category =      
                    'thumb'   ORDER BY uid ASC LIMIT 25");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res)){
        $fname=$row['link'];
        $lname=$row['title'];
        $img=$row['img'];
        $categorie=$row['category'];
        $str = '<a href="' . $row['link'] . '.php">' . substr($row  
['title'],0,11)  . '</a>';?>
        <a href="<?php echo $fname ?>.php"><img src="http://www.website.ro/
images/<?php echo $img; ?>.jpg"/><?php echo $str; ?></a><?php } ?>

</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.thumb{
width:71px;
float:left;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show multiple images on a single line and make it look nice, you need to make sure both width and height are equal for all images and their title.

So you need a container (div) that holds the content for a single image (image & title) and then float that div left with a margin on the right side.

```
<div class='container'>
  <img src='..' alt='image' />
  <div>Image title</div>
</div>
```

style:

```
.container { width:81px; text-align:center; float:left; margin:0px 10px 10px 0px; padding:5px 0 5px 0; }
.container img { width:71px; height:51px; display:block }
.container div { overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:20px; }
```

Now you can put every image in a block like this and it will fill the page where every image + title has the same width and height and so it will show in nice rows and columns

Comment: i understand, thank you ...i will try it, but now everything is clear for me, this will work definitely